# running nx:affected with an xplat workspace

Tags: nrwl-nx

I would like to use the `nx:affected:build` command to only build the apps that are affected by the last commit in an nx/xplat workspace.

Let's say I have 2 angular web apps **web-app1** and **web-app2**.

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── web-app1
│   └── web-app2
├── libs
│   ├── core
│   └── features
│       └── app1
│       └── app2
└── xplat
    └── web
        └── features
            └── app1
            └── app2
```

When I make a change to **/xplat/web/app1** I would expect the `nx:affected:apps` command to only show the `web-app1` app. However nx *thinks* that the commit affects both apps. (**web-app2 ** does not import the app1 feature.)

[image: git log]

```
nx affected:apps --base=head~1 --head=head
```

[image: affected:apps]

I've created a sample repo to demostrate: https://github.com/barryajones/workspace-affected-test